# Does AWS ALB support reverse proxy and post redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-alb

Currently infra has NGINX play as reverse proxy with ELB(classic load balance). would i know whether AWS ALB can achieve similar reverse proxy feature. such as something as below in NGINX:

```
location /v1/ {
     proxy_pass  http://tomcat/serviceA/v1/;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 
     http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
```

it looks ALB can support http redirects but only support GET method. Is it possible for POST?

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that leads you to believe AWS ALB only supports `GET` methods? It supports all HTTP methods (the entire HTTP protocol) as far as I'm aware.

Comment: ALB support ALL of HTTP protocol. but for redirecting to another end-point, looks only support GET. the AWS doc does not mention on it for redirect.

Comment: Have you actually tested this?

Comment: yes, i tested and see GET method in access log after using redirect @ALB